# enabling gzip compression for php setting handler?

Tags: php, compression, gzip, zlib

I have gzip compression enabled in the php.ini file and compression level set to 9. What do I set zlib.output_handler to? Do I leave this blank? and also how would I know if my pages are actually being compressed?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to test if your pages are being compressed is to check the response `Content-Encoding` header value either using Firebug or Chrome developer tools (it will show `gzip` if it's being compressed).

According to php docs:

> You cannot specify additional output
>   handlers if zlib.output_compression is
>   activated here.

So yes, leave it blank.